# AVPlayerViewController did not show video

Tags: objective-c

The below code is not working

```
AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://54.254.248.1/app/webroot/uploads/question_files/2017.04.20.13.43.45video.mp4"];

AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL: url];
AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset: asset];

AVPlayer * player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem: item];

playerViewController.player = player;
[playerViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.width)];

playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = YES;

[self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];

[player play];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i modify your code like this it can work:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://54.254.248.1/app/webroot/uploads/question_files/2017.04.20.13.43.45video.mp4"];
AVPlayer * player = [AVPlayer  playerWithURL:url];

AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];

playerViewController.player = player;
[playerViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.width)];

playerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = YES;

[self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];

[player play];
```

for more information about [AVPlayerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller?language=objc)

Comment: your code is still not working

Comment: have you compiled and tested this code? I have run your code but it does not work on my iphone 5 IOS 10

Comment: sure, but i do not use your url, i replace your url with `https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4`

Comment: please use my url friend

Comment: look this demo https://github.com/jiutianhuanpei/AVPlayerViewController_Demo i change the default with your url，it could play， but  there is no sound，I doubt whether there is any problem with your url。

Comment: ok I will check my recording friend. thx for your information

Comment: Just now, i find the tool to Validator Media Stream，i haven't tried，but hope to help you，https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH102-SW3

Comment: yes I already have checked that it is from my mp4 recording that has no sound,

Comment: ok，there have more introduce about `Best Practices for Creating and Deploying HTTP Live Streaming Media for Apple Devices` https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2224/_index.html

Comment: but can I will create recording without sound and play it?

Comment: sure，the demo [AVPlayerViewController_Demo](https://github.com/jiutianhuanpei/AVPlayerViewController_Demo) plays well，it maybe give you some help。I've used this tripartite library [ijkplayer](https://github.com/Bilibili/ijkplayer), but I feel you don't need to use it.